# Catching Node fs.existsSync errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does it make practical value to put `fs.existsSync` inside `try...catch`?

Is it possible that it will cause an error? How can this happen and which error would it be?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm trying avoid nested `try...catch` if possible.

Comment: What worse could happen with that method. File not exist. Don't seem logical to put it in try catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking [at the (current) implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f85d5b21fda925b879cf27bdcde81478fc134b31/lib/fs.js#L324-L333), it doesn't make sense to wrap it with `try...catch`:

```
fs.existsSync = function(path) {
  try {
    handleError((path = getPathFromURL(path)));
    nullCheck(path);
    binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

`fs.existsSync` cannot `throw` an error.

[Here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L324) is the implementation of `fs.existsSync`, in which `try..catch`es its own errors and returns `false` when an error occurs.